# Vuejs view source - I can still see directives after compilation

Tags: compilation, vue.js

When I compile my vuejs and then do a view source (chrome) I still see the directives and variable place holders?

```
<nav @click="toggleNav"></nav>
<span class="title">{{ pageName }}</span>
```

I am pulling it in via

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

When I try to validate via the W3c I get loads of errors. Should these not be compiled down?

Should I make anything with a directive on it a component so it does not show in my html?

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: The "source" of the page will have the directives. Compilation is done in memory and in the DOM object the browser manages. You will not see these removed from the actual source of the page. You will only see them remove in the "Inspector" view (in Firefox) which shows the current state of the DOM

Comment: Thanks nelson, I can 'ignore' them in the w3c. Nothing to worry about then.